# Compute the histogram entropy estimation of a string

Tags: code-golf, string, probability-theory

Write a program or function that estimates the Shannon entropy of a given string.

If a string has *n* characters, *d* **distinct** characters, *x<sub>i</sub>* is the *i* th distinct character, and *P(x<sub>i</sub>)* is the probability of that character occuring in the string, then our Shannon entropy estimate for that string is given by:

[image: H = -n\sum\limits_{i=1}^d P(x_i) \log_2 P(x_i)]

For the estimation in this challenge we assume that the probability of a character occurring in a string is simply the number of times it occurs divided by the total number of characters.

Your answer must be accurate to at least 3 digits after the period.

---

Test cases:

```
"This is a test.", 45.094
"00001111", 8.000
"cwmfjordbankglyphsvextquiz", 122.211
"             ", 0.0
```

Comment: Opposed to my usual challenges, this one looks complicated, but is actually quite simple :)

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24316

Comment: Is it safe to assume printable ASCII for the input string?

Comment: @TimmyD No. Any string that your language's string type supports.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mathematica's `Entropy` counts bits per character, not total for the string; oh well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>11</s> 8 bytes

```
ċÐ€÷Ll.S
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xIvDkOKCrMO3TGwuUw&input=&args=IlRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0LiI)

Comment: Can I ask, how you enter those characters? With copy and paste?

Comment: At least on Linux, they can all be typed on the US international keyboard.

Answer (score 11):

### Python 3.3+, 64 bytes

```python
import math
lambda s:sum(math.log2(len(s)/s.count(c))for c in s)
```

Got `math.log2` from [mbomb007's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78544/20260).

Comment: So @orlp didn't give us a fully simplified formula, eh...?

Comment: @mbomb007 Depends for what purpose you're simplifying. Writing it in terms of probabilities and distinct characters is natural as a definition, but for golfing it's shorter to work with counts and iterate over all characters.

Comment: Pyth answer with your formula: http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smlclQ%2FQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22This+is+a+test.%22%0A%2200001111%22%0A%22cwmfjordbankglyphsvextquiz%22%0A%22+++++++++++++%22&debug=0 8 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## APL, <s>18</s> 14 bytes

```
+/2⍟≢÷(+/∘.=⍨)
```

This is an unnamed, monadic function train that accepts a string on the right and returns a real.

Like all good things in life, this uses [xnor's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78552/20469). We get a matrix of booleans corresponding to the occurrences of each character in the string using `∘.=⍨`, sum this along the first axis (`+/`) to get the number of occurrences of each character, divide the length of the string by each, then take log base 2 (`2⍟`) and sum.

[Try it here](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190+/2%u235F%u2262%F7%28+/%u2218.%3D%u2368%29%20%u22C4%20f%20%27This%20is%20a%20test.%27%20%u22C4%20f%20%2700001111%27%20%u22C4%20f%20%27cwmfjordbankglyphsvextquiz%27%20%u22C4%20f%20%27%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27&run)

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 58 bytes

A subroutine:

```
{for$a(@a=split'',pop){$t+=(log@a/grep/\Q$a/,@a)/log 2}$t}
```

A tip of my hat to [xnor](/a/78552) for the formula.

Comment: `-F` doesn't work (in Strawberry, anyway) because it includes the `$/`.

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 17 bytes

```
S4#Y'ts/tZl*sGn_*
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=UzQjWSd0cy90Wmwqc0duXyo&input=J1RoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0Lic)

Comment: You may be able to save some bytes with `Ym`

Answer (score 1):

## J - <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
1#.2^.#%1#.=/~
```

Shortened using the idea in Dennis' method.

### Usage

```
   f =: 1#.2^.#%1#.=/~
   f 'This is a test.'
45.0936
   f '00001111'
8
   f 'cwmfjordbankglyphsvextquiz'
122.211
   f '             '
0
```

### Explanation

```
1#.2^.#%1#.=/~  Input: string S
           =/~  Create a table testing for equality
        1#.     Convert each row from a list of base 1 digits to decimal
                This is equivalent to taking the sum and forms a list of tallies
      #         Get the length of S
       %        Divide the length by each tally
   2^.          Log base 2 of each
1#.             "Sum" those values and return
```

Comment: I don't think this counts as a function. If you assign the code to a variable, it does something entirely different.

Comment: @Dennis From what I gather, it appears J interprets it as a chain of compositions, using `3 : '... y'` with the same syntax would be a valid way to define it as a function. J states that it evaluates from right-to-left, so I've refactored my code as a train. I don't like caps `[:` but I can't find any other way to make a train.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 67 bytes

```
s=>[...s].map(c=>t+=Math.log2(s.length/~-s.split(c).length),t=0)&&t
```

I need to use `~-s.split` because that accepts strings rather than regexps. As usual, `map` beats `reduce` by a byte.

```
s=>[...s].reduce((t,c)=>t+Math.log2(s.length/~-s.split(c).length),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
!Gu=stGn/Zl*s|
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IUd1PXN0R24vWmwqc3w&input=J2N3bWZqb3JkYmFua2dseXBoc3ZleHRxdWl6Jw)

```
!      % transpose implicit input into column vector
Gu     % row vector with unique elements of input
=      % test for equality, element-wise with broadcast
s      % sum of each column
tGn/   % duplicate. Divide by number of input characters
Zl     % binary logarithm
*      % element-wise multiplication
s      % sum of array
|      % absolute value. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 37 bytes

```
x->sum(log2(endof(x)./sum(x.==x',1)))
```

Takes a character array as input. [Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZiA9IHgtPnN1bShsb2cyKGVuZG9mKHgpLi9zdW0oeC49PXgnLDEpKSkKCmZvciB4IGluICgiVGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QuIiwgIjAwMDAxMTExIiwgImN3bWZqb3JkYmFua2dseXBoc3ZleHRxdWl6IiwgIiAgICAgICAgICAgICAiKQogICAgcHJpbnRsbihmKFt4Li4uXSkpCmVuZA&input=)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 17 bytes

```
*_lQsm*FlBc/QdlQ{
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2a_lQsm%2aFlBc%2FQdlQ%7B&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22This+is+a+test.%22%0A%2200001111%22%0A%22cwmfjordbankglyphsvextquiz%22%0A%22+++++++++++++%22&debug=0).

Answer (score 0):

## Jolf, 26 bytes

```
_*liuΜGμiEd*γ/l miLeHlimzγ
```

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=XypsaXXOnEfOvGlFZCrOsy9sIG1pTGVIbGltes6z&input=VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QuCgowMDAwMTExMQoKY3dtZmpvcmRiYW5rZ2x5cGhzdmV4dHF1aXoKCiAgICAgICAgICAgICA) (Note that the test suite function is borked.)

### Explanation

```
_*liuΜGμiEd*γ/l miLeHlimzγ
       μi                   unique members of i
      G  E                  split on ""
     Μ    d                 map over function
               _miLeH       match i with regex escaped member
             /l      li     divide length of (^) by length of i
            γ               γ = (^)
           *           mzγ  (^) * log_2(γ)
 *li                        (^) * length of i
_                           negate
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.3+, <s>95</s> <s>91</s> <s>89</s> 85 bytes

Simple solution. Version 3.3 is required to use `math.log2`.

```python
import math
def f(s):C=s.count;return-sum(C(x)*math.log2(C(x)/len(s))for x in set(s))
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/E4NnyF)

Comment: Do you think there's anything unnecessary here? `n*sum(s.count(c)/n`

Comment: @orlp Thanks. I originally had a separate function for finding the probability, but had pasted it inside twice and deleted it to save chars.

Comment: You don't have to store `n` in a variable now that you only use it once.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, 207 bytes

```java
double C(String x,Map<Character,Integer>f){double H=0,g;for(char c:x.toCharArray())f.put(c,f.containsKey(c)?f.get(c)+1:1);for(char c:f.keySet()){g=f.get(c);H+=g*Math.log(g/x.length())/Math.log(2);}return-H;}
```

**Detailed** [try online](http://ideone.com/QyQzLK)

```java
double log2(double d) { return Math.log(d) / Math.log(2); }

double C(String x, Map<Character,Integer>f)
{
    double H=0,g;

    // frequency
    for(char c : x.toCharArray())
    {
        f.put(c, f.containsKey(c) ? f.get(c)+1 : 1);
    }

    // calculate entropy
    for(char c : f.keySet())
    {
        g = f.get(c);
        H += g * log2(g / x.length());
    }

    return -H;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 98 bytes

```
[ [ length ] [ dup [ [ = ] curry dupd count ] { } map-as nip ] bi [ / log 2 log / ] with map sum ]
```

This is a direct translation of [this Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78552/46231). I'll add an explanation over dinner.

Answer (score 0):

## Racket, 130 bytes

:c

```
#lang racket
(require math)(λ(S)(let([s(string->list S)])(sum(map(λ(c)(/(log(/(length s)(count(λ(x)(char=? c x))s)))(log 2)))s))))
```

Translation of my Factor answer, so it's an indirect translation of Kenny Lau's Python answer.

Answer (score 0):

## k (32 bytes)

```
{-+/c*(log c%n:+/c:#:'=x)%log 2}
```

Or in `q`, the translation is not all that short but clearer:

```
{neg sum c*2 xlog c%n:sum c:count each group x}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 45 bytes

```
Tr[Log[2,Tr@#/#]#]&@Values@CharacterCounts@#&
```

### Usage

This returns exact results so we approximate them with `N`.

```
  f = Tr[Log[2,Tr@#/#]#]&@Values@CharacterCounts@#&
  f["This is a test."]//N
45.0936
  f["00001111"]//N
8.
  f["cwmfjordbankglyphsvextquiz"]//N
122.211
  f["             "]//N
0.
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 67 bytes

```
l=length(i<-strsplit(readline(),"")[[1]]);-sum(log2(l/table(i)[i]))
```

#### Explanation

Take input from stdin and split it into a list of characters. (This clunky syntax is why string golf challenges are so tough in R...)

```
         i<-strsplit(readline(),"")[[1]])
```

This assignment is hidden inside of a `length` command, so we get two assignments for the price of one. We have `i`, the list of characters, and `l`, its length.

```
l=length(i<-strsplit(readline(),"")[[1]]);
```

Now we calculate the entropy. R has a nice function `table` which returns the counts of all unique values. For input `This is a test`, `table(i)` returns

```
> table(i)
i
  . a e h i s t T 
3 1 1 1 1 2 3 2 1
```

This is indexed by characters, which is nice, as we can then use `i` as an index to get the count of each character, like so:

```
> table(i)[i]
i
T h i s   i s   a   t e s t . 
1 1 2 3 3 2 3 3 1 3 2 1 3 2 1
```

The rest of the code is then a simple implementation of the entropy formula, flipped around a little.

```
                                           -sum(log2(l/table(i)[i]))
```

Comment: [Save two bytes](https://tio.run/##FcM7CoAwDADQq0inBPygq3oLt9KhSmkDsUoTz18V3iu18sohR01ASyda5GZSkMNnaI3Bv7WjczjLcwJfcQIe1O8cgNCSQ6xmSyTNxzcaRHtTXw) (also your submission does not work on TIO)

Comment: [61 chars using `utf8ToInt`](https://tio.run/##K/r/P822JDEpJ1Uj00a3tCTNIiTfM69Eozg5MU9DR0lJU1PTurg0VyMnP91IA8QwrMnU1C9KLdBI00kDSv5XCsnILFYAokSFktTiEj2l/wA)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 159 bytes

Golfed:

```
string f(string s){var l=s.Length;double sum=0;foreach(var item in s.GroupBy(o=>o)){double p=(double)item.Count()/l;sum+=p*Math.Log(p,2);}return(sum*=-l)+"";}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
string f(string s)
{
  var l = s.Length;
  double sum = 0;
  foreach (var item in s.GroupBy(o => o))
  {
    double p = (double)item.Count() / l;
    sum += p * Math.Log(p, 2);
  }
  return (sum *= -l) + "";
}
```

Test:

```
var codeGolf = new StringHistogramEntropyEstimation();
    Console.WriteLine(codeGolf.f("This is a test.")); //45.0935839298008
    Console.WriteLine(codeGolf.f("00001111")); //8
    Console.WriteLine(codeGolf.f("cwmfjordbankglyphsvextquiz")); //122.211432671668
    Console.WriteLine(codeGolf.f("             ")); //0
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 100 Bytes

```
{a->n=a.size();a.toList().unique().collect{p=a.count(it)/n;p*(Math.log(p)/Math.log(2.0f))}.sum()*-n}
```

### Tests:

```
This is a test. = 45.09358393449714
00001111 = 8.0
cwmfjordbankglyphsvextquiz = 122.21143275636976
aaaaaaaa = -0.0
```